# Default constructor for reference variables (references) in Java

Tags: java, default-constructor

I have the following two classes in Java from which I can use to calculate the results of Complex Numbers.

```
    class Calculator{
       private ComplexNumber compNum1;
       private ComplexNumber compNum2;

    public Calculator(){
        compNum1 = new ComplexNumber();
        compNum2 = new ComplexNumber();
    }

    public Calculator(ComplexNumber compNum1, ComplexNumber compNum2){
        this.compNum1 = compNum1;
        this.compNum2 = compNum2;
    }

    public ComplexNumber addTwoNumbers(){
        ComplexNumber sumOfTwoNumbers = new ComplexNumber();
        sumOfTwoNumbers.real = compNum1.real + compNum2.real;
        sumOfTwoNumbers.imaginary = compNum1.imaginary + compNum2.imaginary;
        return sumOfTwoNumbers;
    }

    public ComplexNumber subTwoNumbers(){
        ComplexNumber differenceOfTwoNumbers = new ComplexNumber();
        differenceOfTwoNumbers.real = compNum1.real - compNum2.real;
        differenceOfTwoNumbers.imaginary = compNum1.imaginary - compNum2.imaginary;
        return differenceOfTwoNumbers;
    }

    public ComplexNumber mulTwoNumbers(){
        ComplexNumber productOfTwoNumbers = new ComplexNumber();
        productOfTwoNumbers.real = (compNum1.real*compNum2.real) - (compNum1.imaginary*compNum2.imaginary);
        productOfTwoNumbers.imaginary = (compNum1.real*compNum2.imaginary) + (compNum1.imaginary*compNum2.real);
        return productOfTwoNumbers;
    }
}

class ComplexNumber{
    public double real;
    public double imaginary;

    public ComplexNumber(){
        real = 0.0;
        imaginary = 0.0;
    }

    public ComplexNumber(double real, double imaginary){
        this.real = real;
        this.imaginary = imaginary;
    }
}
```

There is a Default Constructor that I defined for the **ComplexNumbers** class, but for the **Calculator** class, the datafields are references, not primitive datatypes or even String, should I declare the default constructor for Calculator like what I did in the code??

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, why not?  It's always a good idea to initialize instance variables whether references or primitive.  Sometimes you might have in mind a good reason why someone_ shouldn't_ be able to write `new Calculator()`, but in this case, there would seem to be no harm in allowing that.

Comment: Your ComplexNumber instances should be immutable, like Integer or Double. The fields should be private, with getters for the real and imaginary parts. Then add(), subtract(), etc. should be methods in ComplexNumber, each taking a single Complex argument and returning a new ComplexNumber.

Comment: Why not implement the nullary constructor for `Calculator` as: `public Calculator() { this(new ComplexNumber(), new ComplexNumber()); }`? As for the `ComplexNumber`, fields are automatically assigned to default - no need to explicitly assign them to default in a constructor.

Comment: Thanks <3 ah, the ComplexNumber fields are followed according to an UML Diagram and I'm not the one who decided whether or not it is private or public...